# Awstats - how to disable the robots detection?

Tags: awstats

I can read [here](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_compare.html) that Awstats detects robots/spiders "Report/Filter robots (nb detected)".

Here is a quote from that page:

> AWStats can detect robots visits: All robots among the most common are detected, list is in robotslist.txt (250Kb). Products that are not able to do this give you false information, above all if your site has few visitors. For example, if you're site was submitted to all famous search engines, robots can make 500 visits a month, to find updates or to see if your site is still online. So, if you have only 2000 visits a month, products with no robot detection capabilities will report 2500 visits (A 25% error !). AWStats will report 500 visits from robots and 2000 visits from human visitors.Sawmill Analytics uses a "currently active" list of robots based on the robotstxt.org database.

I can also see from the demo report that it separates bots visits from human visits:
http://www.nltechno.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=destailleur.fr

What I need is to configure Awstats to treat bots visit the same as human. I don't want Awstats to make any difference between robots and humans. All the robots visits should be added to the "Viewed traffic *".

Is that possible to configure Awstats that way? If yes, how? I've been going through the documentation, but I couldn't find anything helpful apart from this one:

```
LevelForRobotsDetection=2 # 0 disables Robots detection.
```

Is that what I am looking for? If I set it to 0, will the bots visits be added to the total visits, or the bots in this case will be deleted from the reports?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Awstats documentation says

```
6.0+ for LevelForFileTypesDetection, LevelForSearchEnginesDetection, LevelForKeywordsDetection, LevelForWormsDetection

# Following values allows you to define accuracy of AWStats entities (robots, 
# browsers, os, referers, file types) detection. 
# It might be a good idea for large web sites or ISP that provides AWStats to 
# high number of customers, to set this parameter to 1 (or 0), instead of 2. 
# Possible values: 
# 0 = No detection, 
# 1 = Medium/Standard detection 
# 2 = Full detection 
# Change : Effective for new updates only 
# Default: 2 (0 for LevelForWormsDetection)
```

So it looks like `LevelForRobotsDetection=0` will do what you want,it should be fairly easy to test too.